# How to Move a Bootstrap Modal Popup using Keyboard Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap's Default Modal Popup here with JQuery UI Draggable Function as shown in the code below in the **[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/z34hqu7x/)**.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#btnTest").click(function() {
     $('.modal').modal({
       keyboard: false,
       show: true
     });
     // Jquery draggable
     $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
       handle: ".modal-header"
     });
   });


 });
```

```css
.modal-header {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
</div>
<div>
  <h4>
Draggable Modal Demo by Vibs
</h4>
  <input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Show Popup" />
</div>
```

Can someone help me to enable functionality which will let me move the modal popup via keyboard's arrow keys of UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#btnTest").click(function() {
     $('.modal').modal({
       keyboard: false,
       show: true
     });
     // Jquery draggable
     $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
       handle: ".modal-header"
     });
   });


$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch (e.which){
    case 37:    //left arrow key
        $(".modal-dialog").finish().animate({
            left: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 38:    //up arrow key
        $(".modal-dialog").finish().animate({
            top: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 39:    //right arrow key
        $(".modal-dialog").finish().animate({
            left: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    case 40:    //bottom arrow key
        $(".modal-dialog").finish().animate({
            top: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    }
});

 });
```

```css
.modal-header {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
</div>
<div>
  <h4>
Draggable Modal Demo by Vibs
</h4>
  <input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Show Popup" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though one thing I'm not able to understand i.e `left: "-=50"` ? Can u explain me why it is in the quotes and how it works theoretically?

Comment: @vibs2006  because for the animate() method all the property names must be camel-cased and values should be inside quotes. "-=50" It is called Relative Values (the value is then relative to the element's current value). This is done by putting += or -= in front of the value.